# How to scroll others element above expandablelistview?

Tags: android

i'm using a expandablelistview but i want that when i expand an group scroll all itens on the layout including my textview and imageview above.

that's my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_destaque"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stub"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_destaque"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lista_destaque"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn1" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap `ImageView`, `Button` and `ExpandableListView` Inside a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` 
e.x.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<ImageView>
<Button>
<ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want imageview, button and expandablelistview to be scrollable.